# How to address mail to a mailing group saved in a shared drive?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have code to send emails to a mailing group from within Excel.

The group (*.msg outlook contact file) is in a shared drive folder and is constantly updated.

I normally manually delete the group contact from my Outlook's "People" tab then drag the updated file into the tab.

Can I automate loading the contact group from the shared drive folder, creating the email, then deleting the group contact?

Or, can I automate reading the group contact list and copying the addresses into the "To" field without loading/deleting the contact group into Outlook?

```
Sub CreateReportEmail()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    Dim BodyString As String
    BodyString = "Body of email"

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = **MailingGroup**
        .Subject = "Bi-weekly report"
        .Body = "Body of email"
        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a text file containing the intended recipients of the email message. If that's the case, you don't necessarily need to worry about creating a contact group in Outlook: You can just open the file, pull the recipients, and add it to the `To` of your email. My suggestion would be to encapsulate the code to get your recipients, so your final code might look something like this:

```
    Sub CreateReportEmail()
        Dim OutApp As Object
        Dim OutMail As Object
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        Dim BodyString As String
        BodyString = "Body of email"

        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = GetMailingGroup
            .Subject = "Bi-weekly report"
            .Body = "Body of email"
            .Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0

        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set OutApp = Nothing
    End Sub

 Function GetMailingGroup() As String
     Dim distList As Outlook.DistListItem
     Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
     Dim emailArray() As String
     Dim i As Integer

     Set oApp = Outlook.Application
     Set distList = oApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("\\nasfsu01\ReDirFold$\RedirectedFolders$\zthurst\Downloads\SHSC Member Services Bilingual Associates.msg")

     ReDim emailArray(1 To distList.MemberCount)

     For i = 1 To distList.MemberCount
        emailArray(i) = distList.GetMember(i).Address
     Next i

     GetMailingGroup = Join(emailArray, ";")
  End Function
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. There is a *.msg contact file.

Comment: You can actually use the same paradigm, and just use the `CreateItemFromTemplate` method in your `GetMailingGroup` function. I updated my answer.

Comment: Runtime error '287': application-defined or object-defined error and it's highlighting "emailArray(i) = distList.GetMember(i).Address". I tried using distList.Display and the group contact displays properly.

Comment: Did you try debugging in the immediate window, to what the value of `i` is, and what member you're on?

Comment: Ok. distList.MemberCount = 75. i = 1. VBA is just not liking my GetMember. I created an outlook.recipient variable to separate the .address property for debugging and "Set distRecip = distList.GetMember(i)" gets highlighted